# Mouse over dbgrid's title

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, tdbgrid

Is there a way to capture name of title with mouse move over Dbgrids title?

Idea is to make title name visible only when cursor is moved over title's field.

Tnx in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code below show how to get the "title" of the grid column the mouse pointer is over.

Actually, what is displayed in the column header of a TDBGrid column is the `Caption` property of the column's `Title` object, which has other properties too.  The code below reads and displays the `Caption` property of the `Title`.

As you can see from the online help, the TColumn objects which are the columns of the grid also have `Field` and `FieldName` properties which you can read if required.

```
procedure TForm1.DBGrid1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y:
    Integer);
var
  Col,
  Row : Integer;
begin
  Col := DBGrid1.MouseCoord(X, Y).X;
  Row := DBGrid1.MouseCoord(X, Y).Y;
  Caption := Format('Col: %d, Row:%d', [Col, Row]);
  if (Col > 0) and (Col <= DBGrid1.Columns.Count) then
    Caption := Caption + DBGrid1.Columns[Col - 1].Title.Caption;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question, what you need to know here is

1: Which cell the mouse is over (and hence whether it is over a title Cell)

and

2: the field name (title).

Both these are possible, but not sure how you would use this information to make the title name visible.

1: is to trap the OnMouseMove event and use the MouseCoord property.

2: is to use the resultant column value (if the Row value is 0) and the Fields[ACol].FieldName property.

But perhaps a more direct way to achieve what you want is to set dgTitleHotTrack in the options and set a hottrack style (which would probably have to be a custom one).

Comment: Not sure how this answers the question. Seems more like a lengthy comment to me.